# Thread pool parametars

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I've been searching everywhere and I need a solution that would let me add 200-300 jobs with a certain function THAT ACCEPTS parameters. I know about delegate and object as single parameter but I was hoping for something that would allow to queue the tasks each with different paramentars instead of object parametar only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
void MyMethod(int param)
{
    ....
}

...

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => MyMethod(1));
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => MyMethod(2));
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => MyMethod(3));
...
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => MyMethod(42));
```

Another option is to make `MyMethod` accept a parameter of type `Object`, and use the second overload of `QueueUserWorkItem`:

```
void MyMethod(object param)
{
    int value = (int)param;
    ....
}

...

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyMethod, 1);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyMethod, 2);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyMethod, 3);
...
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyMethod, 42);
```

Answer (score 1):

simple sample :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(k =>
            {
                TestMethod(k);
            }, i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that prevents you from sending a list of objects as an object parameters, so in practice you can pass any number of parameters to a thread function.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a paramterized thread start(example below)

```
string myUrl = 'asd'
Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(FetchUrl));
t.Start (myUrl);


static void FetchUrl(object url)
{
    // use url here, probably casting it to a known type before use
}
```

or you can use tasks found in System.Threading.Tasks..

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path, response);
                });
```